# Alternative self-hosted web app to Amazon Photos

Tags: open-source

I'm looking for a free, open source if possible, alternative self-hosted web app to Amazon Photos.

The thing is I own a dedicated server where, among other services, I run a Nextcloud service where I also sync personal pictures which I would like to be able to browse through an interface similar to Amazon Photos. The ideal case would be to be able to access a web interface where each user could browse it's own pictures only, no need for othr files as Nextclouds excels here, and if desktop and mobile clients existed and were able to connect to the mentioned Photo app it would be perfect.

Something like Synology Moments would be great.

Anyone knows about an app like this?

Thanks you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Piwigo](https://piwigo.org/). It is open source, can be self hosted and you can control permissions (allow or disallow access to individual images or albums). There is a app for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.piwigo.android) as well as [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/piwigo/id472225196).